# How to use VBA in PowerPoint to open an embedded OLE object

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I think this is a simple question, but I have spent days searching for an answer and nothing yet.

I have an OLE object embedded into a PowerPoint presentation (created using PPT 2010).  I embedded it (a pdf file) through the insert>object>create from file>display as icon method, so that it displays as a little icon on a slide.

My goal is to open it on click of a shape, where the shape is on a different slide from the slide the pdf is on.  The pdf is on slide 5, the trigger shape is on slide 6.  The goal is to open it during slideshow viewing (and it must be done through VBA instead of animations for other reasons).

I thought the following would work:

```
Sub OpenMyDoc()
  ActivePresentation.Slides(5).Shapes("My Doc").OLEFormat.DoVerb(1)
End Sub
```

I had assigned that macro as an on click "action" through the insert>links method.

I have also tried the following variations, with no luck (nothing happens at all when I click on the triggering shape):

```
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.Shapes("My Doc").OLEFormat.DoVerb(1)
```

I also tried:

```
With SlideShowWindows(1).Presentation.Slides(5).Shapes("My Doc")
  OLEFormat.DoVerb(1)
End With
```

I also tried:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides.Item(5).Shapes.Item("My Doc").OLEFormat.DoVerb(1)
```

Other macros (mostly message boxes) in the presentation, and on the same slide work, so I'm sure it's not a permissions or other setting issue.
I am using master slides, but can't seem to trace the problem to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably saw an error message when you ran your code; the error message explains the problem, though in somewhat Microsoftcryptic fashion.  You can only activate OLE objects from Slide or Notes view.

Instead, you can do this:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(4).ActionSettings(1).Hyperlink.Follow
```

where Shapes(4) is hyperlinked to the PDF you want to launch.

[EDIT]

But since hyperlinking isn't an option, and since you have to be in slide view to activate the embedded object, this works here:

' Activate the presentation window 
' You might need to make sure it's in normal view
ActivePresentation.Windows(1).Activate

' Launch the OLE object:
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).OLEFormat.DoVerb (1)

' And immediately switch back to slide show view
SlideShowWindows(1).Activate

Comment: Thanks Steve for the response.  I don't see an error message for the code.  My understanding is that errors that happen in slideshow view don't show up.  So I'm going blind about the problem, but if you have any advice about that it would be great.      I tried your suggestions but (1) I couldn't figure out how to hyperlink to an embedded OLE object, and (2) when I tried it with a hyperlink to a local file it still didn't work (again, no visible error message).

Comment: You wouldn't hyperlink to the embedded object; you'd hyperlink to the external file.  Odd that I both saw an error message here using your code and had it work as expected using mine.  Check your Trust settings; you may have external file links disabled.  Here I got one of those annoying "Are you sure you want to do this" messages before  it would launch the hyperlinked file.

Comment: Thanks again Steve, but with the way the file is set up, I need to use the embedded object, not an external file, so hyperlinking doesn't seem to work.      Also, can you confirm that you get an error message during the slideshow view?  I have seen lots of sources saying that slideshow view doesn't produce errors messages like you would get in the normal view (or when using VBA in other office apps).

Comment: OK, I can understand why a hyperlink might not be acceptable.  But I can confirm the error message during slide show view ("OLEFormat (unknown member): Invalid request. The window must be in slide or notes view."  The sources you've seen might be referring to the fact that bad/erroneous code won't produce compilation errors in slide show view, which I'm pretty sure is correct.  But see the new answer I'm about to post.

Comment: Steve, you are my new lord and savior!  This worked perfectly, and it's so simple.  Thank you.

Comment: I bow before me.  ;-)  It was a great question and we both learned something useful from it.  Thanks!

Comment: Steve- Thanks again.  There is one final hiccup in the solution:  My goal is to ultimately have the file in a .ppsm file, but when I save it to this type the macro stops working.  I have spent some more time trying to figure it out, but can't quite get it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried compiling the VBA?  That might point to any errors that PPT would likely silently ignore during a slide show.  And try setting a break point at the beginning of the routine so you can step through the code as it runs (and verify that it DOES run at all)

Comment: Steve- There were no errors during compiling and I verified that everything runs.  I think I found the problem: In a ppsm file, there is no "window" to activate.  You can see this on a computer with dual monitors.  Usually when you run a full screen slide show you can see the slides (not the presenter view, but the normal view) on the other monitor because there is a window in the background.  However, if you open up a new .ppsm file there is no window on the other monitor, so no window in the background to activate.

Comment: Aha!  I see what you mean.  So another thought:  you should be able to get the path to the current file; call Presentations.Open and pass the path to the file as the first parameter; you may want to do this without a visible window to minimize visual bouncing.  That will give you a presentation window that you can launch the external file from, I think.

Comment: Steve- I'm afraid I don't really follow.  Could you provide some code as an example?  Thanks.

Comment: I tried it and couldn't get it to work, unfortunately.