# Extract embedded pdf from PowerPoint presentation using VBA or VSTO

Tags: vba, vsto, powerpoint

I need to extract embedded (without links) pdf documents in PowerPoint file. I can extract embedded files from Excel using ActiveSheet.OLEObjects and checking for ProgID. Then I copy it to clipboard and save as described [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/717204-need-print-embedded-pdfs-please-help-4.html)
But for some reason I could not find equivalent to Excel.OleObject in PowerPoint. The closest thing I think is `shape.OLEFormat.Object` property but it does not support Copy method. I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550417/programmatically-extract-embedded-file-from-powerpoint-presentation) but if it is possible I need a VBA solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidently noticed that copying the PowerPoint shape itself does the job.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is open the embedded PDF using DoVerb:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).OLEFormat.DoVerb
```

going from there you are depending on your installed software to either address saving the file using SendKeys or if available an API on Adobe Reader.

For a full discussion on this read the thread on the MSDN Forums here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/235dde1a-13bb-4f07-8eb4-04ef1121a747/export-a-pdf-file-from-powerpoint-with-vba?forum=officegeneral

Comment: Added to the above, I found another thread that might be helpful for you on StackOverflow discussing about the same thing you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970827/how-to-use-vba-in-powerpoint-to-open-an-embedded-ole-object